# What do the numbers next to each character indicate?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Fairly straightforward, but when choosing a character to switch to, what do the numbers directly under to Michael, Franklin, and Trevor's photo indicate?

Answer (score 3):

These numbers indicate how many open missions are there in the map for that character to start.

This seems to include main story missions as well as 'Question Mark' missions only available for that character.

It does not include random encounters not visible on the main map as well as pastime activities like races or sport events.